# Is there any way to run a Flutter app through background on macOS or Windows desktop?

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, dart, background-process

I want to make a clipboard application for macOS operating system. For this, the application I wrote with Flutter should continue to work in the background without dying. I've looked at a few resources on this subject. I also reviewed Flutter's own documentation at [this link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes). Background processes can be run on Android and iOS operating systems using isolates. But I couldn't find any information on ways to do this on macOS, Windows, and other desktop operating systems. Is there a way to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that the only way to do this is to work with the native code of the platform. For this, it is necessary to define the Flutter application as a service to the manifest file and set this service to be executed in the background from the native code.

Comment: do you have an example how todo that?

Comment: @smedasn yes, this is a tutorial for definition of a background service for mac os in Swift: https://hoishing.medium.com/providing-services-on-macos-bb82f5e8ca7a ////// in appdelegate or a new swift file, I called the flutter app activity view as a service in the native code